# how to create an array of (100,19) size with each row as a vector of 19 values [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to create an array of size (100,19) in python where each row is a fixed 19 valued vector of value [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]?

Any solution suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**np.full** is a useful function for this purpose:

```
a = [0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
result=np.full((100,19),a )
result.shape
```

output:

```
(100,19)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = np.zeros((100,19))
a[:,11] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = [0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = np.array(a)
c = np.tile(a,(100,1))
c.shape
```

Output:

```
(100, 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with np.zeros

```
array0 = np.zeros((100,19))
array0[:,11] = 1
```

On the other hand, if you want to have all one element

```
array1 = np.ones((100,19))
array1[:,11] = 0
```